# NSTimer - Multiple instances are created

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nstimer, polling

I have an app, which polls to server at regular intervals. The polling is performed using timer task. The timer needs to be used only on one screen, so when I move to other screen, timer is invalidated.

I observed that sometimes the timer gets invalidated, but sometimes not. And when it is not invalidated, multiple instances keep on getting created.

I have initialized timer as follows:

```
 timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 2
                                         target: self
                                       selector: @selector(timerTask:)
                                       userInfo: nil
                                        repeats: YES];
```

And invalidated as follows:

```
if(timer){

    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;


}
```

Please help, what needs to be done in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you creating multiple timers?  In the code snipped you posted above, if a timer is already defined when you execute:

```
 timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 2
                                     target: self
                                   selector: @selector(timerTask:)
                                   userInfo: nil
                                    repeats: YES];
```

any further reference to timer will only give you the newest one created, the only way to get a reference to the original one is to check the argument in your selector and see if it is different from the timer instance variable you defined.

Comment: Yes, when user comes back to the original screen where polling needs to be done, I am re-initializing timer. The problem mainly occurs when I go to next screen -> timer stops -> screen 2 invoked -> back button clicked -> view is removed from superview -> and  here new instance is created. I think this is causing problem. I need timer to resume when back is hit

Answer (score 1):

You should probably create 2 different methods for `starting` and `stopping` the timer, As follows.

```
-(void)startTimer {

     if([timer isValid]) {
         [timer invalidate];
         timer = nil;
      }

     timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 2
                                 target: self
                               selector: @selector(timerTask:)
                               userInfo: nil
                                repeats: YES];
}

-(void)stopTimer {

    if([timer isValid]) {
       [timer invalidate];
       timer = nil;
     }
  }
```

This allows you to `start` the timer, and if the instance is already valid it will invalidate it and start a new one. Stopping it will invalidate it, and `timer` is ready to be initialized on your next `startTimer` call.

Hope this helps !

Comment: I did this, but still the same problem...please help..stuck till  now

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way to "resume" an NSTimer. You could create a couple of properties to keep track of the date (which includes time) when the timer is created, and when screen 2 is invoked.  When you move to screen 2, invalidate the timer, when you go back to screen 1, get the time difference between your 2 date objects, subtract that from the time you want between polling, and create a new timer with that time interval. This would appear to be a "resume" of the timer to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should `retain` the `NSTimer` object.

```
timer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 2
                                          target: self
                                        selector: @selector(timerTask:)
                                        userInfo: nil
                                         repeats: YES] retain];
```

and invalidate

```
if(timer){

    [timer invalidate];
    [timer release];
    timer = nil;
}
```

Comment: If I release timer, the app is crashing